# How can I export my old emails from a private server to Gmail servers?

Tags: email, gmail, export

Let's suposse I have a lot of emails in a private email server. Organized in folders, subfolders, tags, etc.

I want to migrate all this emails (with their current organization) to a new email domain provided by Google and their services. Is there a clean and easy way to achieve this? Or it all depends on the email client I'm currently using?

I could use some tutorials for this but I don't know exactly what to look for...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set up IMAP on both and then use a multi-server IMAP client to transfer them. Note that Gmail uses labels, not folders, so don't expect it to be a perfectly clean transfer.

Comment: Thanks @Ignacio , I'll try that but I've been told that these multi-server IMAP client sometimes hung up unexpectly when they are transfering huge amounts of emails (I'm transfering like 25 accounts with +/- 1gb of emails data each).

And btw, Gmail has support for folders with emails :)

Answer (score 1):

As ignatio said, I'd use IMAP to transfer files between accounts. Take a look at [imapsync](http://imapsync.lamiral.info) ([README](http://imapsync.lamiral.info/README)); it's quite powerful and up to date.